# matplotlib doesn't show lines

Tags: matplotlib, octave

I have a data file exported from octave which include two vectors x and u0 . I want to plot u0 versus x in matplotlib with the following codes

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat')
x = data['x'] 
u0 = data['u0']


plt.plot(x,u0)

plt.show()
```

The above codes gives just a blank figure 
[image]

When I changed the line `plt.plot(x,u0)` with `plt.plot(x,u0,'-bo')` I got the following

[image]

Why solid line does not appear?

Here is the data [myfile.mat](http://speedy.sh/Jdu4C/myfile.mat)

Comment: what are the shapes of `x` and `u0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suspect that your data arrays have a shape of `(N, 1)` ie `[[0], [0], ...]` which matplotlib in broadcasting (correctly) to `N` 1-point lines.

Try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x.flatten(), u0.flatten())
plt.show()
```